# Event handers on same event and node run in inverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tweaking some old code (thus the style inconsistencies) organised like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/page.js"></script>
```

### general.js

```
jQuery(function($){
    if( typeof FileReader !== "undefined" ){
        $('form[enctype="multipart/form-data"]').each(function(){
            $(this).on("change", "input:file", function(event){
                // Code to abort upload if file is too lage
                alert("Sorry, file is too large");
                $(this).val("");
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });
        });
    }
});

var addAdditionalField = function(event){
    // Code to add an additional field if needed
}
```

## page.js

```
$(function(){
    $("input:file").change(addAdditionalField);
});
```

I need that event handlers run in the order I define them:

1. Size check
2. Add fields

... so I'm able to abort the second one from the first one. But as [the fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/brurh1mj/1/) I'm getting the inverse order (you need to select a file, no need to actually upload it).

Can you spot the issue?

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/brurh1mj/1/

Comment: @ssilas777 That's my fiddle. I think you forgot to click "Update" :-?

Comment: ah rit :).. any way you cracked the issue, I was trying to show you this https://jsfiddle.net/brurh1mj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first handler is bound on the form whereas your second handler is bound to your input element.

Since jQuery uses event bubbling the event first triggers on your input element (fires the 2nd handler) and then on your form (where it filters for only input elements and then fires the 1st handler)

Changing your 2nd bind to

```
$('form[enctype="multipart/form-data"]').on("change", "input:file", function(event){
    ...
```

is one way to solve your problem (you can make the first selector more specific if you want to just do this for a specific form on the page).

Comment: Additionally, this binding can be used in both files (there's no need to `.each()` the forms and then seek for file controls). That solves this and other issues present in actual codebase.

Comment: Cool. Many problems with one fix! :-)